# Unable to add fixed / static email address while send an email using Email Template using Power Automate

Tags: dynamics-crm, power-automate, dynamics-365, email-templates

I created a workflow in Power Automate to send an email based on the Dynamics 365 email template. The email functionality worked fine until I added a fixed email address under Perform an unbound action step (shown in the red border under the screenshot).

I have taken a reference from the below link
[Power Automate: Send an email using the Email Template](https://www.inogic.com/blog/2020/09/power-automate-send-an-email-using-the-email-template-part-1/)

Below is the code snippet which I have added for a fixed email address,

```
{
“addressused”: “hello@contoso.com”,
“participationtypemask”: 3
}
```

Below is the screenshot of error in my power-automate / flow
[image]

Can anyone help me with the same?

Answer (score 2):

Hard to tell if there are more than the issue I have identified because you haven’t given us the JSON as text.

However, you have two comma’s as shown, fix that and try again.

[image]

Further to the above, I suspect you'll have issues with the last property there ... `@odata.type` ... it won't like that.

You'll need to remediate that as well by working around the issue, this is a potential approach ...

```
"@{string('@')}odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.email"
```

`@` signs are reserved characters in PowerAutomate expressions.

Comment: I have replaced this line and now it is working. Thanks

Comment: Then please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to @Skin's answer - the double-quotes in the red box don't look like standard plain double-quotes, they look like open and close quotes. Check that they are "..." and not “...”. Watch out for this when copying from blogs/sites.

Comment: I have tried as you had suggested but I need to replace "@{string('@')}odata.type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.email" line  for resolve the issue. Thsnks